# No virtual method startDragAndDrop

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I'm following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-bndS0Z4r8 tutorial but get this error. Please help.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    findViewById(R.id.textView).setOnLongClickListener(longListen);
    findViewById(R.id.textView2).setOnLongClickListener(longListen);
    findViewById(R.id.textView3).setOnLongClickListener(longListen);
}
View.OnLongClickListener longListen = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        DragShadow dragShadow = new DragShadow(v);

        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("",  "");
            v.startDragAndDrop(data,dragShadow,v,0);

        return false;
    }
};

private class DragShadow extends View.DragShadowBuilder{

    ColorDrawable grayBox;

    DragShadow(View view) {
        super(view);
        grayBox = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point outShadowSize, Point outShadowTouchPoint) {
        super.onProvideShadowMetrics(outShadowSize,outShadowTouchPoint);
       View v =getView();

        int h = v.getHeight()/2;
        int w = v.getWidth()/2;

        grayBox.setBounds(0,0,w,h);

        outShadowSize.set(w,h);

        outShadowTouchPoint.set(w/2,h/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
       grayBox.draw(canvas);

    }
}
```

Main_Activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:baselineAligned="false">


<TextView
    android:text="Test 1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.25" />

<TextView
    android:text="Test2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.25" />

<TextView
    android:text="Test3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.25" />

<TextView
    android:text="Drop target"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.25" />
```

The error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.moon.draganddrop, PID: 3077
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method startDragAndDrop(Landroid/content/ClipData;Landroid/view/View$DragShadowBuilder;Ljava/lang/Object;I)Z in class Landroid/view/View; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.View' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
                  at com.example.moon.draganddrop.MainActivity$1.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:41)
                  at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5237)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9228)
                  at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21121)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Basically I want to create a drag and drop application.The process is when the textview is clicked and move it to the drop target it will trigger something such as changing the background color. But i'm still stuck with this problem. Please help. I'm such a noob.

Comment: The object View, doesnt have a startDragAndDrop method, so you can call it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the current version of the device API you are trying to exploit. The StartDragAndDrop method only works from API version 24 or Nougat (android 7.0) up. To solve you should add:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   v.startDragAndDrop(data,dragShadow,v,0);
} else {
   v.startDrag(data,dragShadow,v,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `startDrag()` instead of `startDragAndDrop()`. It's marked as deprecated but it works, unlike `startDragAndDrop()`. It's probably got something to do with the API version.